# the event that was called from window1 to window 2 in WPF Not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
**
```

> I have 2 windows in app. mainwindow with 2 buttons and window1 with a
> label. btn one opens window1 and btn 2 changes window1 label color.

**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window

{

Window1 sWindow = new Window1();public MainWindow()

{InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnFirstWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       sWindow.Show();
    }

    private void btnChangeBackground_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       
        sWindow.ChangeBackground();
    }
}
```

> public partial class Window1 : Window
> {

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ChangeBackground()
    {

        
        if (lblShowUser.Background == Brushes.Green)
        {

            lblShowUser.Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Red, Colors.Red, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            lblShowUser.Background = Brushes.Green;
        }
    }

}
```

> IF I remove this part
> **
> private void btnFirstWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> {
> sWindow.Show();
> }
> ** From mainwindow and add both windows at app xaml
> Startup="App_Startup"
> StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
>
> public partial class App : Application
> {
> void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
> {
> Window1 sWindow = new Window1();

```
        sWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

> the method of label changing color when i press the other button doesnt work
> am new to C# and wpf So when answering please also give explantion on what to be done to the code and why
>
> expecting it to work even if changes are made regarding when the other page shows up but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Create an object as a field from `Window1` class, then you can access its objects.

Output (tested in Visual Studio 2017, .Net Framework 4.5.2):
[image: Output]
**Note: if this solution helps you, please mark as answer (don't forget to vote for me).**

XAML (Mainwindow):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="OpenButton" Click="OpenButton_Click" Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Margin="99,0,0,0"/>
    <Button x:Name="ChangeColorButton" Click="ChangeColorButton_Click" Content="Changing color" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="99" Margin="331,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML (Window1):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Closing="Window_Closing" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="Label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C# (MainWindow):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window1 W1 = new Window1();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        W1.ShowDialog();
        
    }
    private void ChangeColorButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        W1.Label.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }
}
```

C# (Window1):

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Thanks